L'utilisation des pronoms "son" et "ses" qui ne renvoient pas à la même personne dans la même phrase est-elle conforme aux règles du français?
Exemple:
Carol a préféré ne pas développer davantage sa relation avec Gabriel, inquiet que son physique ne corresponde pas à ses attentes.

"Son" fait référence à Carol.
"Ses" fait référence à Gabriel.

Si ce n'est pas correct, pourriez-vous générer des versions plus correctes sur le plan sémantique. Merci

La phrase est tout à fait correcte pour moi,  c'est la logique qui guide le raisonnement dans l'interprétation des sentiments. Je ne vois pas comment on pourrait interpréter la phrase autrement.

En fait le problème est sémantique et stylistique et non syntaxique: il vient de ce que les indices grammaticaux ne suffisent pas à déterminer qui est possesseur de quoi. Il existe aussi, avec les mêmes remèdes, dans les langues germaniques, atténué par le changement de forme du possessif selon le genre grammatical du possesseur.

personnellement j'avais lu la phrase dans l'autre sens (Carol a préféré ne pas développer davantage sa relation avec Gabriel, inquiet que le physique de ce dernier ne corresponde pas à ses propres attentes). J'imaginais un contexte de rencontre en ligne, où Carol se basait sur les photos pour juger du physique de Gabriel. Je pense donc qu'une clarification est bienvenue.

How about “son physique à elle” and “ses attentes à lui”?

@PaulTanenbaum That's rather be an answer or a suggestion to mine. Anyway, à elle and à lui would definitely clarify the meaning too (unless Carol is masculine in which case using pronouns wouldn't help). Using à elle/lui emphasizes a lot who it is about so might considered a little heavy style, more oral French than literary.

Agreed, @jlliagre: cette option ne s’offre comme clarification que quand les deux individus diffèrent en genre. But hey, such lucky alignment of the stars often allows writers (or, per your comment, more likely  speakers?) to dodge bullets.

Please clarify whether Carol is male or female. Spelled that way, it's not a (common) French name.

Il n'y a rien à redire sur la syntaxe comme déjà dit en commentaire.
Néanmoins, s'il fallait lever tout doute sur le sens de la phrase, on pourrait écrire :

Carol a préféré ne pas développer davantage sa relation avec Gabriel, inquiet que son propre physique ne corresponde pas aux attentes de ce dernier. (si Carol est un prénom masculin)


Carol a préféré ne pas développer davantage sa relation avec Gabriel, inquiète que son propre physique ne corresponde pas aux attentes de ce dernier. (Carol féminin, le plus courant, en français Carole)

Si, comme l'a envisagé @AloisChristen, le sens attendu est l'inverse duprécédent :

Carol a préféré ne pas développer davantage sa relation avec Gabriel, inquiète (ou inquiet) que le physique de ce dernier ne corresponde pas à ses propres attentes.


Si Carol est un prénom utilisé au masculin, l'ambiguïté du son est levée par l'ajout de ‘propre’ et ‘attentes’ ; sinon ‘inquiète’ semble plus approprié, “n'est-il pas” ?

@Personne Ok Carole!
