Est-il grammaticalement admissible d'utiliser le pronom "il" à plusieurs reprises dans une phrase lorsqu'il se réfère à des individus distincts ?
Exemple:

Marc a indiqué à Jonas que si jamais il (Jonas) perdait son emploi
chez SNB, il lui offrirait un poste au sein de sa compagnie
d'entretien, Imbèque.

Si la phrase pose problème sur le plan sémantique, pourriez-vous la modifier de manière à la rendre correcte sans pour autant corrompre l'empreinte stylistique du texte original. Et si votre créativité est au rendez-vous, je vous serais reconnaissant de me générer d'autres phrases reflétant le sens attendu mais avec une structure et un style distincts. D'autre part, certaines des stratégies de rédaction présentées dans une question similaire impliquant des pronoms possessifs ne sont pas applicables aux pronoms personnels.

Les locutions celui-ci, ce dernier, celui-là sont pile-poil faites pour désambiguer les pronoms personnels. Une seule précision est suffisante pour désambiguer toute la phrase: Si jamais celui-ci perdait son emploi chez SNB, il lui offrirait un poste... : celui-ci est nécessairement Jonas (celui-là serait Marc) et, vu le contexte, est ce même lui à qui un poste serait offert. Il est donc Marc.

@دولةفلسطين Je doute que la question soit posée pour la 1ère fois sur ce site.

@FrançoisJurain Je ne crois pas qu'elle l'ait jamais été en revanche, l'auteur de celle-ci a déjà posé une question très similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54714/lutilisation-des-pronoms-son-et-ses-qui-ne-renvoient-pas-%c3%a0-la-m%c3%aame-personne

@دولةفلسطين Merci, c'est je crois ce que j'avais en tête. VTC car duplicate.

This question is similar to: L'utilisation des pronoms "son" et "ses" qui ne renvoient pas à la même personne dans la même phrase est-elle conforme aux règles du français?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Pour enlever toute ambiguité, on pourrait reformuler ainsi la phrase : "Si jamais Jonas perdait son emploi chez SNB,  Marc lui a indiqué qu'il lui offrirait un poste au sein de sa compagnie d'entretien".
